# Why does the % function not work in this case?

Tags: python, zero

Here is some code I have been working on to find a list of prime numbers (bear in mind I am fairly new and I know this will seem over complex)

```
prime_list=[2,3,5,7,11,13]

prime_list=[2,3,5,7,11,13]

a=1
length=len(prime_list)
last=prime_list[length-1]



true=True
while last < last**2 and a <30:
    last= last+1
    a=a+1
    for number in prime_list:
        if (last)%number == 0:
            true = False
        else:
            pass
    if true == True:
        prime_list.append(last)
    else:
        print("n")
        pass

print(prime_list)
```

The essence of the problem is this, all I get is `ns`. As in, the true variable is always made false. For some reason the remainder function isn't working. I would really appreciate some help. (For the specific section involved look at the `if last%number == 0:`

Comment: `while last < last**2 ...` doesn't make sense if you keep increasing `last`...

Comment: What is this code supposed to do ? you already hard-codede a list of primes. You shouldn't assume that we will understand what you intended to do just by reading your code. What are you trying to do ? where do you fail ? what is a wanted output vs. actual output ?

Comment: Please don't name a variable that can be False `true`.

Comment: Continuing from @DanielRoseman, name it `flag` instead

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this if you are a beginner:

```
def isPrime(x): # define a function that will check if 'x' is prime
    if x == 2:
        return True
    i = 2
    while i * i <= x: # this will loop from i = 2 to sqrt(x)
        if x % i == 0: # check if 'i' can divide 'x'
            return False
        i += 1 # this will increase 'i' by 1
    return True

n = 100 # every prime number in 'list' will be below 'n'
list = [] 
for k in range(1, n):
    if isPrime(k): # let see if 'k' is a prime number
        list.append(k) # if 'k' is a prime number add it to the list
print(list)
```

For a more efficient algorithm I would use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `last` is not working in your code is that it needs to be defined outside of the `while` loop. Here is a simple way to do it. Notice that the prime list, and nextNum (my equivalent to your `last`) are defined globally. Because they are defined outside the `while` loop, they will persist from iteration to iteration.

```
primes = []

nextNum = 2
while nextNum < 100 :
    tester = 0 # 0 at the end means nextNum is prime
    for p in primes :
        if nextNum%p == 0 :
            tester += 1
    if tester == 0 :
        primes.append(nextNum)
        print nextNum
    nextNum += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never resetting `true` (which really is a bad name for this variable) to True after it gets set to False once.

Move `true = True` into your while loop before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first number you are testing (14) is not primary, so the flag (variable named `true`) is set to `False`. So far so good. The bad thing is that the flag never changes since then, and remains `False` for all subsequent numbers: there is nothing that could reset it to `True`.

You need to set the flag variable to `True` for each number you test, before you start iterating over potential dividers.
That is, the operator `true=True` (I hate writing this) should be inside `while`, not before it.

P.S. Operator `%` works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

What martijnn replied is perhaps the best example for a beginner. If we want to apply his example to a particular list you have made, like you did in your original code (just so you can see a difference from a mandatory 100 loop, and you can learn more about lists and loops):

```
original_list=[2,3,5,6,7,11,13]
prime_list = []

def isPrime(x): # define a function that will check if 'x' is prime
    if x == 2:
        return True
    i = 2
    while i * i <= x: # this will loop from i = 2 to sqrt(x)
        if x % i == 0: # check if 'i' can divide 'x'
            return False
        i += 1 # this will increase 'i' by 1
    return True

for k in original_list:
    if isPrime(k):
        prime_list.append(k)

print prime_list
```